XLS rendering format is not available
I am currently supporting the .NET project [MVC] that uses Telerik.Reporting.R3.2017, HTML5ReportViewer[MVC], and .NET Framework 4.5.2 The user can get Telerik report in two ways.

The user can render the report [based on criteria] in the browser viewer and then use export option in the viewer to get "XLS" format. This works all fine.
Another way to get report is using RenderReport function of Telerik.Reporting Which created file at specific location.

When User run report in report viewer and Export to Excel (.xls) it works all fine. However, when RenderReport function of Telerik.Reporting [Which creates Excel(.xls) file at specific location], Application throws error of "XLS rendering format is not available"
Unfortunately, unable to get this work even after detailed investigation and going through same post on Telerik forum.
your assistance is much appreciated
Thanks,
